# Employer-funded pension in Germany

Tags: germany

My employment contract to Germany mentions about an employer-funded pension. What does it mean? How will it affect my gross salary?

Answer (score 1):

Your employer has to make contributions to your pension, your social security, and your health insurance in addition to your gross salary.

You should ask your employer whether you have to make contributions to your pension (this is the normal case), or whether they make all the contributions (this is unlikely).

The HR department of your employer should be able to provide a detailed breakdown (even if the HR/admin department is one part-time secretary).